# In LINQ-To-SQL, should I use NOLOCK to improve performance?

Tags: linq-to-sql, nolock

Our DBA came to us with information that our LINQ queries are creating many thousands of locks on the database. A developer on our team dug up this Hanselman post as a possible solution to our problem:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx

Scott provides 3 ways in LINQ for setting NOLOCK. 1) TransactionScope (preferred), 2) SPROCS, 3) context.ExecuteCommand

We are a news site that is 99% reads, 1% writes so our major focus is on the speed of retrieval. Is **NOLOCK** a good strategy for all our LINQ-TO-SQL queries?

What I'm trying to understand is **why** using NOLOCK is or isn't a good idea. There must be a lot of people with our same goals: many fast reads, little to no updates. If NOLOCK is the obvious answer, then why isn't it the default? Why can't I make it a default on the context, instead of having to set it in every single data call?

Is NOLOCK really the best option for the many fast reads, few updates site?

**UPDATE: In SQL Server 2005 and above, Is Snapshot isolation better than NOLOCK?**
I just found this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179599.aspx

which covers **READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT**. This prevents write-block, but doesn't return dirty data? Should this be used 90% of the time over NOLOCK?

**UPDATE 2: What's bothering me is DRY**

The part that's bothering me most is that in order to implement either a no-lock or snapshot pattern, I have to change it on EVERY LINQ-to-SQL query method (except those being used in updates). This smells like a major violation of DRY.

Comment: It's good for its speed - it's bad because you might end up getting data back that's not been committed yet ("dirty data") and that might end up being rolled back and not persisted...

Comment: What is an example of how uncommitted data comes back? A write that was done as part of a transaction, but rolled back?

Comment: yes, if you happen to read the table in the middle of someone else writing data to it inside a transaction, you'll get that uncommitted data back, which could be incomplete, or that other process could then decide to roll back the transaction in the end, so your read got some data that isn't in the table in the end..

Comment: On the "related" pane on the right, there are about 2-dozen questions asking about NOLOCK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth noting: `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` is (or at least was 2+ years ago) good enough for [the site you're using](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html).